# How to create Mountpoints for Logical Volumes

Tags: bash, redhat, rhel6, mount-point

I have a script that I want to help me create a Logical Volume Manager with partitions outlined below:

```
# Partitioning scheme for 120 GB HD

# Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel
# Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr
# Disk partitioning information
part /boot --fstype="ext4" --size=256
part swap --fstype="swap" --size=16384
part /PV --fstype="ext4" <96> size=1 --grow --encrypted --passphrase=password
volgroup sysvg /PV
logvol / --vgname=sysvg --size=5120 --name=root
logvol /tmp --vgname=sysvg --size=2048 --name=tmp
logvol /usr --vgname=sysvg --size=4096 --name=usr
logvol /home --vgname=sysvg --size=20480 --name=home
logvol /opt --vgname=sysvg --size=5120 --name=opt
logvol /var --vgname=sysvg --size=5120 --name=var
logvol /var/log --vgname=sysvg --size=10240 --name=log
logvol /var/log/audit --vgname=sysvg --size=5120 --name=audit
```

Every time I try to incorporate this into my build I am getting an error saying that it cannot find a mount point.  I am not sure why it is saying that if my mountpoints are outlined above.  Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What distro is this..?

i se  a "usr enter code her logvol /home"

Means it proberly for linux and you should be looking at /etc/fstab

## EDIT

Try look at parted commands http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#Partitioning
and some
grub-install mbr or just plain mbr packages